# HighCharts: Reaching options of other charts from point event

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to  change selected option of a chart point when one of the chart's point is selected.

For example: Suppose there are two pie chart and one point of first one is selected. If i clicked one of the point of second one i want to set false the selected option of first's point.

[image]

```
point: {
events: {
click: function() {         
              closeOlderOne(...);
         }
    }
},
```

...

```
data:[{
    sliced: false,
    selected: false,
    selection: '1', ...
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/u7FQS/110/

Comment: yes, you did it by using only one chart, thats okey for solution of my problem. However this question is not asking that, i think that this cant show as a solution.

Comment: So you have two separeted charts.

Comment: Yes because there are some div between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to catch click event on the point and "reset" status on each slice on next chart. See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/u7FQS/118/

```
 point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        $.each(chart2.series[0].data, function (i, data) {
                            data.slice(false);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: There is a problem about reopen second time. Try to open same selection first time at chart1 after chart2 after again chart1.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? I'm still coudnt change anything.

Comment: You need to add return false in the end of chart, and slice current element manually. it is realted with animations, so please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/u7FQS/121/